# Javascript is treating variables as Strings, why?

Tags: javascript, string, variables

I have the variable y, which is a subtotal. Its value is different depending on what happens with the html, but throughout the script I declared it like this:

```
var y = 21.78;
```

etc. Why is it that on my last equation where I add up the total, it treats them as strings when I want to add the values?

```
var tax = (0.055*y).toFixed(2);
var totalprice = y+tax;
/* totalprice holds "21.781.20" instead of 22.98 */
```

Comment: @Radu no, just a series of if else statements. y is always equal to a number like that, no other variables are involved in declaring it.

Comment: For a question to be answerable, the problem must be reproducible. Please include [minimal sample code](http://sscce.org/): complete, concise and representative. Read [Writing the Perfect Queston](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints/) for  more guidelines.

Comment: @outis - ooh I like that answer. I'm gonna have to save that somewhere so I can re-use it.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the sample code *is* complete. It' so rare that three lines is enough, I leapt to the conclusion it wasn't.

Comment: He could have done it with one line using commas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

`toFixed()` returns:

> A string representation of number that does not use exponential
>   notation and has exactly digits digits after the decimal place.

thus, `y+tax` is cast to a string since one of the operands is a string.

In my opinion, this would make sense as Javascript's intrinsic numeric types do not have the ability to store a specific number of decimal place digits, so a string would be the most appropriate data structure to store this with.

I would advise you do all your addition *before* calling `toFixed()`, since the method is most suitable for formatting display output.

```js
var taxRate = 0.055;
var subtotal = 21.78;

var tax = (taxRate * subtotal).toFixed(2),
totalprice = ((1+taxRate) * subtotal).toFixed(2);
document.write(totalprice);
```

Answer (score 3):

The .toFixed() method returns a string. Try applying that method as the last step after all other calculations.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple fix. Put '+' in front of the tax variable to convert it to a number.

```
var y = 21.78;
var tax = (0.055*y).toFixed(2);
var totalprice = y+ (+tax);
totalprice === 22.98;
```

If you don't want any rounding errors when you use toFixed, then include this re-implementation of it in your script.
http://bateru.com/news/2012/03/reimplementation-of-number-prototype-tofixed/

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, if there's any chance available, Javascript will see the "+" sign as concatenate rather than addition. It's driven me nuts on more than one occasion. I will generally do this rather than chance concatenation:

```
var totalprice = parseInt(y)+parseInt(tax);
```

Comment: typeof is your friend. So is an hour or two of googling how JS's dynamic type casting/conversion works. Much easier than hitting everything with the parse mallet which would have caused you problems in this case. You'll want parseFloat for numbers with decimals. parseInt(0.55) returns 0.

Answer (score -1):

When letter replaces value, multiply with `1` when you're in need of `+`.

```
var totalprice = (y*1) + tax .
```

Other operands work fine, it's just the `+` operand that needs special treatment when variable replace value.

Comment: Did you test this? It doesn't work. `y` is already a number and multiplying it by 1 won't do anything. The problem is that `tax` is a string. Also, what's the period doing at the end of the line?